# When Microsoft turned Skype into Web Application?

Tags: discussion, migration

Can someone explain to me, how this [question about Skype](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/61143/any-way-to-change-skype-profile-picture-on-line) can be migrated to Web Applications, because it is found off-topic in Super User? Exactly since when Microsoft has turned its base communication program into web app?

Comment: _But, is there any way to do this on-line, directly from_ ***Skype website***

Comment: God! We're talking about **web profile** of **perfectly standalone program**. Skype **isn't a web application**, now matter, how you look at it! Beside seeing / editing profile and topping up your account you _can't do nothing_ through website. You can't call etc. As I understand "web application" definition, it says, that you operate all or most of its functionality through web browser. This definition has noting to do with Skype!

Comment: You're talking about doing something via we application. Whether or not it exists is a different thing altogether

Comment: I understand, that you call Word 2010 a web application as well, because it has Office Online port and you can download something from the website in it. You can't do nothing (like text editing) through website in this version of Word, but thinking the way you think, makes Word 2010 a web application, right?

Comment: If you're asking about the Web version of Word then yes, that constitutes as a web app and will be(and has been) migrated

Comment: @trejder it was migrated because you explicitly say that you want to do it via the website (i.e. Webapp) and and **not** the desktop application. One of these is on topic here, the other is not.

Comment: Please refrain from yelling at my elected moderators.  I rather like them and their feelings can easily be hurt.  Besides, doing so leads me to lend little to none sympathy toward your cause.

Comment: @KronoS I had a really bad day and I'm really sorry for that. Does this lend a little more of your sympathy toward me? :] Also, please take a look at my suggestion below Sathya's answer.

Comment: @all Sorry for taking this too emotional and too personal! :[

Comment: @trejder I'll be merciful this once ;).

Comment: For what it's worth, [Skype for Web](https://web.skype.com/) is currently in beta testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, your question explicitly asks

> But, is there any way to do this **on-line, directly from Skype website?**

From [Super User's Help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> and it is not about …
>
> **websites** or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

ergo, it's not on topic. Whether or not Skype is a full blown desktop app isn't relevant, you're asking for something which needs to be done from it's Web application equivalent and hence was migrated

Comment: I have accepted your answer, as all of you had finally convinced me. This, however, doesn't change the fact, that in my opinion, Help part you cite is very misleading. Out of three examples it uses, all three are full-blown web applications, while we have an example here of using just a small web-part in full-blown desktop application (both Skype and Word 2010 examples matches). IMHO you should consider extending help to add example like this -- that questions about using web clients or parts of desktop applications are considered off-topic here and will be closed or migrated. Thanks!

Comment: @trejder it's pretty difficult to capture the idea of partial WebApp or the WebApp aspect within a help center.